# R: getting google finance JSON data into a dataframe

Tags: json, r, google-finance-api

I am trying to get google finance JSON data into a dataframe.
I tried:

```
 library(jsonlite)
dat1 <- fromJSON("http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:%20AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,AMZN,IBM")
dat1
```

However I get an error:

> Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
>     parse error: trailing garbage

Thank you for any help.

Comment: just realized your question was asked for R in specific. My answer was for Python. They're pretty similar, however, so i'm hoping that you can use what i posted regardless to find a solution. If not, let me know if its completely not useful in which case ill remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not replicate your error using `fromJSON` due to proxy issues from my side but the following works using `httr`

```
require(jsonlite)
require(httr)

#Set your proxy setting if needed
#set_config(use_proxy(url='hostname',port= port,username="",password=""))

url.name = "http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:%20AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,AMZN,IBM"

url.get = GET(url.name)


#parsing the content as json results in similar error as you encountered

#url.content = content(url.get,type="application/json")
#Error in parseJSON(txt) : parse error: trailing garbage
#          " : "0.57" ,"yld" : "2.46" } ,{ "id": "358464" ,"t" : "MSFT"
#                     (right here) ------^





#read content as html text
url.content = content(url.get, as="text")

#remove html tags
clean.text = gsub("<.*?>", "", url.content)

#remove residual text
clean.text = gsub("\\n|\\//","",clean.text)

DF = fromJSON(clean.text)

head(DF[,1:10],5)

#        id    t      e      l  l_fix  l_cur s        ltt                 lt               lt_dts
#1    22144 AAPL NASDAQ  92.51  92.51  92.51 1 4:00PM EDT May 11, 4:00PM EDT 2016-05-11T16:00:02Z
#2   358464 MSFT NASDAQ  51.05  51.05  51.05 1 4:00PM EDT May 11, 4:00PM EDT 2016-05-11T16:00:02Z
#3 12607212 TSLA NASDAQ 208.96 208.96 208.96 1 4:00PM EDT May 11, 4:00PM EDT 2016-05-11T16:00:02Z
#4   660463 AMZN NASDAQ 713.23 713.23 713.23 1 4:00PM EDT May 11, 4:00PM EDT 2016-05-11T16:00:02Z
#5    18241  IBM   NYSE 148.95 148.95 148.95 2 6:59PM EDT May 11, 6:59PM EDT 2016-05-11T18:59:12Z
```

Comment: That is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the below code from [here](https://github.com/hamiltonkibbe/stocks). Let me know if this helps.  On a side note, I would also recommend netfonds.  Netfonds is the only source I've found that provides intra-day ***tick*** level data for both historical prices and the open book.  I posted some additional links below for pulling the Netfonds data if you're interested.

http://www.blackarbs.com/blog/3/22/2015/how-to-get-free-intraday-stock-data-from-netfonds

http://www.onestepremoved.com/free-stock-data/

```
import urllib
from datetime import date, datetime

""" googlefinance
This module provides a Python API for retrieving stock data from Google Finance.
"""
_month_dict = {
        'Jan': 1,
        'Feb': 2,
        'Mar': 3,
        'Apr': 4,
        'May': 5,
        'Jun': 6,
        'Jul': 7,
        'Aug': 8,
        'Sep': 9,
        'Oct': 10,
        'Nov': 11,
        'Dec': 12}


# Google doesn't like Python's user agent...
class FirefoxOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'

def __request(symbol):
    url = 'http://google.com/finance/historical?q=%s&output=csv' % symbol
    opener = FirefoxOpener()
    return opener.open(url).read().strip().strip('"')


def get_historical_prices(symbol, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    """
    Get historical prices for the given ticker symbol.
    Returns a nested list. fields are Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume.
    """

    price_data = [data.split(',') for data in __request(symbol).split('\n')[1:]]
    for quote in price_data:
        quote[0] = _format_date(quote[0])
    return price_data

def _format_date(datestr):
    """ Change datestr from google format ('20-Jul-12') to the format yahoo uses ('2012-07-20')
    """
    parts = datestr.split('-')
    day = int(parts[0])
    month = _month_dict[parts[1]]
    year = int('20'+ parts[2])
    return date(year, month, day).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting to see a Python solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the Google finance endpoint returns a newline delimited json, the solution in R should be:

```
library(jsonlite)    
dat1 <- stream_in(url("http://www.google.com/finance/info?q=NSE:%20AAPL,MSFT,TSLA,AMZN,IBM"))
```

But it seems the endpoint is not accepting such request (any more?):

> HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'